# c# Given 2 numbers X and Y, make X approach Y but not surpass it

Tags: c#, math

I've been racking my brains for ages trying to work out a good formula for this.

Essentially what i want is given 2 numbers X and Y, I would like X to approach Y but not surpass it depending on the difference between the 2 numbers.

Both X and Y are floats between 0 and 1.

Examples:

- X = 0 Y = 1. X should become about 0.7-0.8 ish.
- X = 0.5 Y = 1 X should become between 0.8-0.9.
- X = 0.9 y = 1 X should become 0.97 ish.

Heres what i've tried:

- (1-X) * Y = Just gives linear progression....
- 0.08/(1.1-(Y-X)) - Better.. but gives a value 0.13 when the difference is 0.5, 0.8 when the difference is 1 and 0.4 when the difference is 0.9.... not quite what i wanted...

Any ideas guys?

Thanks,

Phil.

Comment: No attempt?? wtf I said heres what i've tried i've been thinking of different ways to solve this for hours tbh.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/), seeing as there is nothing programming specific about it.

Comment: What is the criterion? I mean, it becomes 0.7-0.8 or something based on what? Percentage of the difference? Initial value?

Comment: You problem is called interpolation. There is infinite number of solutions to your problem also. So, instead of writing "it should be close", bring a pen and draw coordinates for each z=f(x,y) with say, 0.2 step from 0 to 1 for each {x} and {y}, this way we will be able to barelly answer the question.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE4UA4dMbBM) might be helpful. (caution, it's very mathy).

Comment: @eocron Interpolation is a part of this problem, but I don't think it's the main part.  He needs to first find the formula for the curve he wants that has a specific vertical [asymptote](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Asymptote.html).  Then he can just input `X` and get `Y` from that formula.

Comment: OP, just halve the distance each time. `x = x + (y-x)/2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
Single x = 0.0f;
Single y = 1.0f;

Single z = x + ((y - x) * 0.75f);

Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("N4")); // 0.7500
```

For `x = 0.5` it gives `0.8750`.

For `x = 0.9` it gives `0.9750`.

In order to tweak the result and make it as close as possible to your expectations, just play with the scalar `0.75f`.

Working environment:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Single y = 1.0f;
    Single scalar = 0.75f;

    Console.WriteLine(Calculate(0.0f,y,scalar).ToString("N4"));
    Console.WriteLine(Calculate(0.5f,y,scalar).ToString("N4"));
    Console.WriteLine(Calculate(0.9f,y,scalar).ToString("N4"));
}

public static Single Calculate(Single x, Single y, Single scalar)
{
    return x + ((y - x) * scalar);
}
```

What you are trying to implement looks to me line a sort of [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation).

Comment: thanks, was thinking about it and i think i was trying to over complicate it lol

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell what's the perfect value for you, but you can basically use a generic formula for blending between two points, coordinates, or whatever:

x = a × x<sub>1</sub> + (1 - a) × x<sub>2</sub>

The same can be done for `y` or any other value, even whole vectors or points.

To apply this to your specific variables:

X<sub>new</sub> = a × X + (1 - a) × Y

`a` basically determines the position relative between the first and the second point. `0` means the point is on the first one, `0.5` puts the point exactly in the middle, and `1` represents the second point.

How you change `a` over time depends on which kind of tweening you want (e.g. linear, quadratic, ease-in, ease-out, etc.

If you want to read more regarding this topic, try looking for *tweens*, *tweening*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
y- y * Math.sqrt(y-x)*0.25
```

Just a quick idea. It works for your test cases (kind of).

- 0.75
- 0.82
- 0.92

Answer (score -1):

```
float Result(float x, float y)
{
    return y - ((y - x) / 4); // you can change 4 to whatever you need.
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not the one who down-voted, but if you plug this in to a graphing calculator, with the numbers he provided [0,1], you just get a vertical line at 1, instead of a curve approaching 1 asymptotically.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thanks. I see that you (and possibly the downvoter too) assume OP wants the limit of an infinite number of these calculations. By OP's examples I thought they only wanted it once. (It would help, of course, if they came around and told us what they meant...) Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible I interpreted the question completely incorrectly, but it isn't clear at all.  I think they are using the same variable for multiple purposes (If X = 0, how can it get closer to anything, let alone move at all?)